# Laravel return variable in blade template

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have a route like below.

```
Route::get('profile/{username}', 'ProfileController@index');
```

ProfileController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    function index() {
        view('profile.index');
    }
}
```

profile/index.blade.php

```
{username}
```

But it doesn't echo the username when I go to `/profile/salep`, what's missing here?

If I change my ProfileController to this (below), it works but PhpStorm says "Unreachable stamement" for the view.

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    function index($username) {
        return $username;
        view('profile.index');
    }
}
```

I didn't use the structure below (took it from the documentation) because I need to pass my variable to a view rather than returning, so I need to both return and pass it to a view, I guess.

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
    return 'User '.$id;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

routes.php

```
Route::get('profile/{username}', 'ProfileController@index');
```

ProfileController.php

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    function index($username) {
        return view('profile.index')->with('username', $username);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there with the second attempt.

Try this:

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    function index($username) {
        return view('profile.index')->with('username', $username);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already figured it out and added the exact answer a minute ago, but thanks! :)